# Why can't I drag Remote App windows that can be merged?

Tags: azure, remote-desktop, rdp, remoteapp

We are currently in the process of migrating from Azure RemoteApp to another RemoteApp deployment as the current version goes end of life soon. An issue has been raised in UAT whereby Windows cannot be dragged across the screen for more than a split second (only seems to occur in instances where the Window in question is primed to be merged with another Window).

Here are two such examples:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1S4OHN3Sdfyck13UVFzT0c1eWM
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1S4OHN3SdfyOHg4WlJmVGdIQTQ

This problem seems to only occur when connecting to Remote Apps via Windows 7 (which is what our users use). When tested in Windows 10 and OSX there was no problem. We also tested this inside a Remote Desktop and it was working.

Our current live deployment doesn't have this issue (connecting to Windows Server 2012). The deployment with the problem is using Windows Server 2016 so we spun up a host server using Server 2012 and still had the same problem.

We have also tried modifiying settings in the connection file to eleviate the problem. These are some of the settings that didn't seem to help the problem when we changed them:

- bitmapcachepersistenable
- disable full window drag
- disable menu anims
- disable themes
- enablesuperpan

Has anyone come across with problem or know how to fix it? I'm happy to answer any questions about our setup.

Comment: Have you tried using Windows 10 client? Does the issue happen there as well?

Comment: @cdavid "When tested in Windows 10 and OSX there was no problem." Unfortunately all our users are on Windows 7